# EDAC: Could not find mci handler

Tags: kernel, 15.10, edac

After installing Ubuntu 15.10 x64 on my desktop computer yesterday I am no longer able to boot into the system. A text message comes up saying:

```
EDAC: ECC is disabled.
EDAC: Couldn't find mci handler.
```

Surprisingly that exact same message also appeared when installing Ubuntu.

My hardware is an ASUS X99 motherboard, i7-5930K with Crucial CT2K8G4DFD8213 DDR4 RAM. None of them support ECC.

How can I fix this Kernel error?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I had to enter the BIOS and do nothing then exit the BIOS (which automatically reboots) then Ubuntu starts.